# Spring Boot: Rest endpoint integration with Kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Working on a rest endpoint which has to send a message to another service to process. It is a microservice architecture and all the services are connected via Kafka message broker.

Spring supports `@Async` for asynchronous methods but it doesn't work as expected. Code is something like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/responses/{id}", produces = "application/json")
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Response> getResponseById(@PathVariable @Valid Long id) {
  //some code
  producer.send(id);
  //other service will send the response back and kafka consumer will save it to the db
  responseRepository.findById(id);
}
```

It doesn't wait for the message to come back from kafka.

What is missing here?

Comment: I'm missing something here I think. As far as I know `@Async` is in no way related to Kafka, so why do you mention Kafka in your question? Additionally, `@Async` methods with return type require you to use `Future`s, and I'm not seeing those in you question either.

Comment: Good catch. I have updated my code with `CompletableFuture`. The way I understood `@Async` is for asynchronous methods.

Comment: `Producer.send` is asynchronous.  https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord)

Nowhere do you wait for a message back.  You just send your message and query the db immediately.

Comment: @Taylor how should I do it?

Comment: Kafka is used for asynchronous distributed messaging.  If you want to wait for a reply, this can be achieved with Kafka but it's unnecessarily complex.  You'd have to send the message and keep checking the database until you see what you expect.  Consider leveraging HTTP (e.g. REST) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sync(blocking) method to send message
`producer.send(id).get();` 
This will make execution wait for the result.